# latitude and longitude in $cordovaGeolocation returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Right now I am building an ionic app to get user location and launch
 them to a particular place an event we be held- But first, I save the
 user latitude and longitude to firebase and then when the user click
 **Launch Navigation** the **launchNavigator()** method we be launch.
 but the issue is that the latitude and longitude is returning
undefined

Here is my code:

```
    app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($timeout, $scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $localStorage, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, PresenceService,
    $ionicLoading, HomeService, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaLaunchNavigator){

          $scope.Data ={
            lat : '',
            long: ''
          };
          $scope.Get  =HomeService;
             $scope.hasMore  =   function(){
                 $scope.check    =ListAllUserService.hasMore;
                 return  $scope.check;
             };
             $scope.LoadAllUser  =function(){
                 $ionicLoading.show({template:'Loading...'});
                 $scope.Get.load().then(function(data){
                     $scope.data    =data;
                     console.log($scope.data);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();

                     var posOptions = {timeout: 40000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
                       $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)

                       .then(function (position) {
                          var lat  = position.coords.latitude
                          var long = position.coords.longitude
                          console.log(lat + '   ' + long);

                          $scope.Data.lat  =lat;
                          $scope.Data.long =long;

                            var dataToDb         =  {latitude: lat, longitude: long, timestamp: new Date().getTime()};
                            var InsertChatRef = new Firebase('https://bigzill.firebaseio.com');
                            var insertObj   =InsertChatRef.child('GeoLocation').child($scope.data.username);
                            insertObj.push(dataToDb);

                       }, function(err) {
                          console.log(err)
                       });
                 });
             }
          $scope.LoadAllUser();
          $scope.launch = function(){
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                                    title : "GPS navigation"+ $localStorage.lat,
                                    template: "Navigation Launch"+ $localStorage.long
                                });
          }
           $scope.launchNavigator = function() {

        $ionicPopup.alert({
           title : "GPS Just Launch"+ $scope.Data.lat,
           template: "Navigation Launch"+ $scope.Data.long
        });

                 var lat    =$scope.Data.lat;
                 var long   =$scope.Data.long;
                 console.log(lat + '   ' + long);
                var destination = [lat, long];
                var start = "Benin City, Oka Market";
                $cordovaLaunchNavigator.navigate(destination, start).then(function() {
                    console.log("Navigator launched");
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title : "GPS navigation",
                        template: "Navigation Launch"
                    });
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    console.log(lat + '   ' + long);
                     $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title : "GPS fail "+ lat,
                        template: "Navigation Launch "+ long
                     });
                });
           };
    });
```

Here is my Html

```html
    <ion-view view-title="Home Page">
        <ion-content class="has-tabs" style="">
            <div class="list card">
                <div class="item item-avatar">
                    <img ng-src="{{data.image_name}}">
                    <h2>{{data.username}}</h2>
                    <p>November 05, 1955</p>
                </div>

                <div class="item item-body">
                    <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{data.image_name}}">
                    <p>
                        This is a "Facebook" styled Card. The header is created from a Thumbnail List item,
                        the content is from a card-body consisting of an image and paragraph text. The footer
                        consists of tabs, icons aligned left, within the card-footer.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
                        <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
                        <a href="#" class="subdued" ng-model="Data.lat">{{Data.lat}} ' lat'</a>
                        <a href="#" class="subdued" ng-model="Data.long">{{Data.long}} ' long'</a>
                        <div ng-click="launchNavigator()">Launch Navigation</div>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```